# tensorflow 2.0 gpu set available gpu?

Tags: gpu, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

def get_available_gpus():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos if x.device_type == 'GPU']
get_available_gpus()
```

> ['/device:GPU:0', '/device:GPU:1']
>   I want to set the available gpu when I train and compile the cnn with tensorflow 2.0 gpu
>   how should I do that?

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1";  
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.8
tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

some how this code is not woriking

> tf.**version** '2.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your script, it looks quite right already. As far as I understand keras for tensorflow 2.x has it own high-level API called keras. 
I also use

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
```

and

```
try:
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
  pass
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

Also you may want to switch to

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

You can find the reason from this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/). 
I think first you can test with pre-built (say VGG or ResNet) model to see if your GPU runs or not. 
I am pretty sure that some of my custom build models don't really use GPU. but when I run with another model it works. It's kinda weird and the problem lies in the model I assume.

Answer (score 0):

Use `with tf.device():`
So, you now have two GPUs with names:

```
['/device:GPU:0', '/device:GPU:1']
```

Then in your code, for example your main job:

```
def main():
    # do somthing here...
```

In main():

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'): # select device here...
        main()
```